# Is there any way to accomplish something like List<object> list = new List<int>() in C#?

Tags: c#, generics

That is the question. What I want to accomplish is something similar to the following Java code:

```
class A { }
class B extends A { }

public class Tests {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        ArrayList<? extends A> lists = new ArrayList<B>(); 
    }
}
```

*(in which `B extends A` means B inherits from A)*

Is it possible at all?

Thanks

Comment: No, and it shouldn't be in Java, either; that was a mistake on their part (they tried to fix it by breaking generic arrays instead, which only made things worse).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. While C# 4.0 introduces the concept of variance for interfaces, it isn't (and can't be) possible to do what you're asking specifically.

In C# 4.0, you can do this:

<strike>`IEnumerable<object> foo = new List<int>();`</strike>

---

*Edit*: As Marc points out, this can't be done with value types and reference Types. However, since I think your question was more about a generalized `A:B` than it was about `int:object`, I think the point carries. To be accurate, though, what I mean is that C# 4.0 will allow something *this*:

```
IEnumerable<object> foo = new List<string>();
```

---

But you can't do what you describe. Namely, let's consider:

```
List<int> foo = new List<int>();
List<object> bar = foo;

bar.Add("baz");
```

Now, what happens when we try to access `foo[0]`? You've now broken the type safety on the list.

Comment: @devoured elysium: In C# 4, generic variance is possible for certain *interfaces* - it is never possible from one generic class to another generic class. So what you could do in C# 4 would be something like: `IEnumerable<A> list = new List<B>();`

Comment: The variance doesn't extend between ref-types and value-types. It would work with `IEnumerable<object> foo = List<string>`, but not `int`.

Comment: @Marc: Thanks for the clarification; I wasn't aware of that caveat. I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet with `List<object>` would be to just use the non-generic `IList`:

```
IList list = new List<int>();
```

However! *Adding* something other than `int` will cause a runtime exception.